# rpd over https using a linux client

Tags: linux

I [posted this on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/197890/rpd-over-https-using-a-linux-client) but I thought *this* would be the better audience. (So sorry for crossposting...)

My employer switched from vpn and rdp to using what our admin calls "rdp over https".
Since that switch I find myself unable to connect to the "new" rdp server.

I *think* the progress is as follows:

- A rdp gateway-server is connected via tls
- the requested sever (different from the gateway-server) is then connected through the tls connection.

In windows mstsc-settings the server name is the "internal network name" of the machine I wish to connect. And on the last tab (in German it is called "leistung" - could be activity) I go to the "connection from everywhere" settings and set the gateway-server under gateway-server.

Now:
Is there **any** way to use this scenario under linux (apart from a virtual machine   running Windows)?
I am interested in

- free ideas (e.g. is it possible to create a tls tunnel and connect through that using freerdp/rdesktop?)
- non-free ideas. As long as they work I'll worry about the costs later.

Free ideas would be better :-)

On SuperUser I got the idea to expose an ssh server and tunnel rdp through it. This is a valid idea but not feasible in my case. I really need a Idea to connect to the rdp server via the gateway-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one (!) software that can do this:
http://itap-mobile.com/desktop/rdp/ brings iTap - an rdp connection software that comes for 20 € plus tax. It is not open source but it is a solution to my "problem"... They have a test-version, too.

iTap seems to run under GNU/Linux and Mac.
I have tried it with my employers setup and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

I did some more research and it looks like it's *NOT* simply rdp tunneled over tls.  So, stunnel is not going to work for this scenario.

Now, I still don't know exactly how the gateway works - the protocols could be standard, or they could be some proprietary thing that Microsoft put together.  But who knows - you might get lucky and it be something standard.

The next thing I would try is [ProxyTunnel](http://proxytunnel.sourceforge.net/usage.php).  If the gateway is a standard CONNECT proxy, then it might work.  The command would be something along these lines -

```
proxytunnel -a local_port -p gateway_server:port -d destination_server:port
```

then rdp to localhost on local_port.

I can't promise it'll work, but it's worth a try...

---

If it's just a simple tls proxy, (plain rdp is tunneled over tls) you can try [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/).

Set up an stunnel from localhost:some_port to gateway:rdp_port, then point your rdp client to localhost:some_port.

But if there's some other protocol involved (other than rdp and tls) then you're likely to need a client that supports that protocol. In which case, does the MS RDP client work under WINE?

Comment: regarding stunnel: I would need a setup like this: localhost:1025 via gateway:443 to target:rdp_port.  Would that be possible using stunnel?

Comment: regarding mstsc/wine: no (tried it), see also http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17714

Comment: regarding proxytunnel: It does not work. However I did not manage to get error-messages out of proxytunnel, so I do not know what the problem was..

Comment: Without a server to test against, or more information about the protocols in use, I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions.